# runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode *temp1=l1; //linked-list l1
    ListNode *temp2=l2; //linked-list l2
    ListNode *head=l2;
    while(temp1!=nullptr || temp2!=nullptr){
        if((temp1->val + temp2->val) > 9){   // This line shows the error
            temp2->val = (temp1->val + temp2->val) % 10;
        if(temp2->next!=nullptr)
            temp2->next->val += 1;
        else
            temp2->val = 10;
        }      
        temp1=temp1->next;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    return reverse(head);    
}
```

I was solving leetcode "Add Two Numbers", i.e, adding two linked list problem, where I coded this way, I think there is some error behind it, But, I can't get it and understand what and why is this error coming.

Please, help me out!

Comment: `while(temp1!=nullptr || temp2!=nullptr)` - one of further dereferenced pointers can be nullptr

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, i didn' get it, And,   " if((temp1->val + temp2->val) > 9){   // This line shows the error "

Comment: @AsitKumar `temp1 != nullptr || temp2 != nullptr` will be true as long as one of `temp1` & `temp2` is non-null - so one of those two is allowed to be a nullptr by your condition. The `if()` statement on the next line however requires both to be non-null (otherwise you'd dereference a nullptr which is undefined behaviour)